# How to use holoeverywhere in the intellij idea? Can I use the holoeverywhere in the finished project under 2.3?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-holo-everywhere

I imported holoeverywhere like jar in project. But when I tried use theme, nothing not changed. What should I do to make it work?

```
package com.example.testholo;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;


        public class MyActivity extends Activity {
            /**
             * Called when the activity is first created.
             */

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                setTheme(com.actionbarsherlock.R.style.Holo_Theme_Fullscreen);
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
            }

    }
```

I also have a project under 2.3. How сan I use the holoeverywhere in the finished project under 2.3?

Comment: Extend the Activities from org.holoeverywhere.app.***Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open module settings - Libraries - + - From Maven - type org.holoeverywhere:library:1.5.0 - OK.
Specify some dirs and IDEA should automatically import and connect HoloEverywhere from the maven repo.
Also see a demo project - you are should use org.holoeverywhere.* classes, not android.*.